# Generally how much time is spent in reviewing an undergraduate/graduate applications to universities

Tags: graduate-admissions, professorship

Generally, how much time does a professor grant to review a single application?

With thousands of applications, how is it ensured that each application is given proper weightage and importance because applying filters might not always work.

Some person who is good at one thing, might not be for the other. So predefined filters would act against him.

Comment: Undergraduate and graduate applications are completely different. You should ask about one at a time. Although undergrad applications are not reviewed by professors.

Comment: @AzorAhai - and undergrad admissions is specifically off-topic here.

Comment: @JonCuster I always interpreted that as questions like "Am I good enough for University of X?" I think procedural questions could be answered, but didn't want to start that debate.